# Advice on maintaining dev and live environment in SVN

Tags: svn, project-management, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN as version control for my project.

We have now completed UAT for project phase 1 and are about to put the web app live.

My problem is if I continue to develop phase 2 of the project in SVN, what if the client requests a small change to the live system, how can i do this from SVN?

Do I have to maintain 2 SVN repositories?

What is best practice as this must arise quite a lot for other developers...

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open a branch for your current "development" and keep the trunk for your "production" version.

#### Example: live version 1.0

```
YOUR REPO
/trunk/html/
/trunk/html/file1.php
/trunk/html/file2.php
```

#### Example: dev version 1.1

```
YOUR REPO
/branches/dev/html/
/branches/dev/html/file1.php
/branches/dev/html/file2.php
```

Then, you and your fellow developers will work on the branch `dev` while the live environment server is checked out form the `trunk`

We have a structure like this with an integration server, a staging server and a live server with different clients.

If you want take a look to this:

#### http://api.mutado.com/mobile/svndeploy/

It's an open source project (it's also available on GitHub) we did to keep our staging and live environments synchronized with SVN. It's web based then you can updates your remote working copies without using SSH accesses.

Hope it helps.
Ciao!

Answer (score 3):

Use Subversion tags for identifying specific snapshots (deployed versions), and Subversion branches for historical versions of the code that are in use and may need small changes or bugfixes independent from trunk development. For some commonly used repository layouts see [Common Branching Patterns](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html) in the "Version Control with Subversion" book.